# Finding x'y' coordinates from xy coordinates with unit basis vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

I wasn't really sure where to get started with this question as I don't fully understand what it's asking.. I can see that u1 is made up of i + j (or u2) and that x' is scaled for some scalar k from vector u1 and same occurs with y' from u2. However I don't know how to find the x'y' coordinates given the xy coordinates.

Comment: It might be easier to convert $\mathbf{u}_1 = (1, 30^\circ)_\text{polar}$ to rectangular first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way:

Write $\mathbf u_1,\mathbf u_2$ in rectangular coordinates:

$$x = r \cos \theta$$ $$y = r \sin \theta$$

Then use the formula:

$$\begin{bmatrix} \\ \mathbf{u}_1 && \mathbf {u}_2 \\ \\ \end{bmatrix}^{-1}\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix} = \left[{\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix}}\right]_\mathcal{B}$$

and I assume you know the shortcut for finding the inverse of a $2 \times 2$; Google it if you don't.

Here $\left[{\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix}}\right]_\mathcal{B}$ is the vector $\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix}$ written in the coordinate system defined by $\mathcal{B} = \left\{{\mathbf u_1, \mathbf u_2}\right\}$. That is, it's the vector your problem calls $\begin{bmatrix} x' \\ y' \end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: This is using change of basis method? I'll update my question with my attempt. Also I'm a little unsure of my values for the vectors. And if this is using change of basis method, shouldn't B = {i, j} vectors instead of u1, u2 since the coordinates x, y are in respect to {i, j} and the coordinates x', y' are in respect to {u1, u2} (from the question)?

Comment: I'm not sure what this method is called. Both my answer and @CottonTensor 's method should work.

Comment: As to which basis you use to create the inverse matrix, it depends in which direction you're converting. This is how you convert *to* $\mathcal B$ *from* the standard basis $(\mathbf{i,j})$. I edited my answer to hopefully make myself more clear.

Comment: Could you give any tips for finding the inverse, I was going to use guassian jordan method but it's a little tricky with the identity of u1. Is there any easier way that I can avoid using the trigonometric identities for u1 and u2. Since u1 = (cos(30), sin(30))

Comment: There is a shortcut for the inverse of a $2 \times 2$: http://tinyurl.com/nwr46wz .

Answer (score 1):

Consider a vector $\vec{v}$. Now express this in each of the co-ordinate systems. $\vec{v} = x \vec{i} + y \vec{j}$. Similarly $\vec{v} = x' \vec{u_1} + y' \vec{u_2}$. Now you need to use the fact that they both represent the same vector. So take dot product of $\vec{v}$ with $\vec{i}$ and $\vec{j}$ in both co-ordinates and equate them.

$\vec{v}.\vec{i} = x = x' \vec{u_1}.\vec{i} + y' \vec{u_2}.\vec{i} = x' \cos (30^\circ) \Longrightarrow x' = \frac{x}{\cos (30^{\circ})}$

$\vec{v}.\vec{j} = y = x' \vec{u_1}.\vec{j} + y' \vec{u_2}.\vec{j} = x' \cos (60^\circ) + y' \Longrightarrow y' = y - x \frac{\cos (60^{\circ})}{\cos (30^{\circ})} $